# When multiple NSTextViews are present in a window, the one receiving typed keys isn't necessarily the one receiving command-keys. Why?

Tags: swift, macos, nstextview, first-responder, nsresponder

I am having a hard time understanding the responder chain in OS X.

I have an NSTextView subclass, and I want it to respond to a command-key and do something. I've created a very simple demonstration of my problem. Anyone interested can see if with only a couple minute's effort.

Create a new OS X project, and here is the only additional code you need. Make a new class in Swift named MyTextView (subclass of NSTextView) and paste this into it:

```
import Cocoa

class MyTextView: NSTextView {

    // listen for a command key
    override func performKeyEquivalent(theEvent: NSEvent) -> Bool {

        // if it's a cmd-equals, change the background
        if theEvent.characters == "=" && theEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.CommandKeyMask) {
            Swift.print(theEvent)
            self.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
                green: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
                blue: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
                alpha: 1.0)
            return true
        }
        return super.performKeyEquivalent(theEvent)
    }
}
```

Now in your storyboard, place 2 or more NSTextViews into the same contentView. Under the Identity Inspector, **tell each NSTextView its class is MyTextView** (the NSTextView is nested a bit: NSScrollView > NSClipView > NSTextView).

Run the project. Hit cmd-equal. One of the textviews changes its background color, but it isn't necessarily the one that possesses the cursor, which is receiving all the other key-presses. It isn't necessarily the one that starts out with the cursor. And if you place the cursor in a different textView, it still doesn't change which one responds to the command key.

Why is that? Why isn't the textview that's receiving the typed keystrokes the same textview that's receiving the command-keys? Clearly the textviews know who is supposed to be receiving the keystrokes, because typing works. But my command-key goes to somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. MyTextView needs to test whether it is the FirstResponder. If it is, it consumes the event. If it isn't, it doesn't.

```
override func performKeyEquivalent(theEvent: NSEvent) -> Bool {

    if self.window?.firstResponder == self {
        // if it's a cmd-equals, change the background
        if theEvent.characters == "=" && theEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.CommandKeyMask) {
            Swift.print(theEvent)
            self.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
                green: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
                blue: CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
                alpha: 1.0)
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.performKeyEquivalent(theEvent)
}
```

Comment: I wish I could give you 100 up vote :). Your solution just save me few hour debugging, since I don't understand why the text view which received command key is not the one that get the event